# What does maps.nokia.com use?

Tags: javascript, tiles

The maps on [maps.nokia.com](http://www.maps.nokia.com) are pretty amazing. I assume they're generating their own tiles but, does anyone know about the infrastructure behind site: the tile server used? and their JavaScript Library?

Comment: @StephenLead yeah the transitions and zoom-in/zoom-out are especially smooth. I'd like to do and equivalent of this with Leaflet.

Comment: Fastest tileserver I've seen. Half the wait time of anything else, and the transitions make it feel like less!

Comment: Nokia maps tile servers, are used by Yahoo, Bing and Facebook. That's a lot of traffic, they need to be fast.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nokia owns [Navteq](http://corporate.navteq.com/company_history.htm) (acquired in 2008 for $8.1bn)

**4 Tile Servers with pre caching**

```
1.maptile.lbs.ovi.com/maptiler/v2
2.maptile.lbs.ovi.com/maptiler/v2
3.maptile.lbs.ovi.com/maptiler/v2
4.maptile.lbs.ovi.com/maptiler/v2
```

They do generate their own tiles from this vector data into raster tiled png format (256px x 256px) files 
[image]

one example is
http://1.maptile.lbs.ovi.com/maptiler/v2/maptile/newest/normal.day/13/4399/2685/256/png8?token=gBoUkAMoxoqIWfxWA5DuMQ&app_id=_peU-uCkp-j8ovkzFGNU

The Map Tiler Servers are:

```
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat)
Last-Modified: Mon, 09 Jul 2012 18:02:00 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
ETag: a2e328a0c5
Content-Length: 21651
X-NLP-IRT: D=84337
Content-Type: image/png
X-Served-By: 77.124
Cache-Control: public, max-age=86386
Date: Thu, 19 Jul 2012 18:15:14 GMT
```

The still use the old OVI MAPS API rebranded as Nokia Maps
http://api.maps.nokia.com/en/index.html

you can test at the Nokia Maps API playground

http://api.maps.nokia.com/en/playground/env/desktop/

Comment: Disclamier - was a beta tester for ovi maps api (100+ feature requests) but they keep on improving.